# Magento 2 cannot update module with composer

Tags: magento2, module, composer

I'm trying to update a module from Mageworx , currently I have the version 2.31.0, it's "mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate": "^2.30", there is not something like an specific module called module-seosuiteultimate in vendor folder.

So everytime I try to update it to version 2.31, with this commad:

```
composer require mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate:2.31
```

It throws this error:

```
Problem 1 
    - Installation request for mageworx/module-xmlsitemap (locked at 3.0.4) -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-xmlsitemap[3.0.4].
    - mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate 2.32.2 requires mageworx/module-xmlsitemap 3.2.1 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-xmlsitemap[3.2.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install mageworx/module-xmlsitemap 3.2.1
    - mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate 2.32.0 requires mageworx/module-xmlsitemap 3.2.0 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-xmlsitemap[3.2.0].
    - mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate 2.32.1 requires mageworx/module-xmlsitemap 3.2.0 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-xmlsitemap[3.2.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install mageworx/module-xmlsitemap 3.2.0
    - Installation request for mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate ^2.32 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate[2.32.0, 2.32.1, 2.32.2].
```

So then I try to update mageworx/module-xmlsitemap to the version that is required 3.2.1. and it showes me this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate 2.30.4 requires mageworx/module-xmlsitemap 3.0.4 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-xmlsitemap[3.0.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate 2.30.4 requires mageworx/module-xmlsitemap 3.0.4 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-xmlsitemap[3.0.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate 2.30.4 requires mageworx/module-xmlsitemap 3.0.4 -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-xmlsitemap[3.0.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate (locked at 2.30.4, required as ^2.30) -> satisfiable by mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate[2.30.4].
```

So practically, I cannot update any of those 2 modules, what is going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## First

What does your `require` section look like in your `composer.json` file. Are there more than one mageworx packages being required?

## Second

I'm looking at the `composer.lock` for a client of mine that has that mageworx extension installed. Looks like that is a composer metapackage that installed a bunch of mageworx extensions.

That would mean that each package installed for this metapackage is **locked** at the version it's at. I believe that would explain why trying to update the main metapackage fails.

```
    {
        "name": "mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate",
        "version": "2.31.0",
        "require": {
            "mageworx/module-htmlsitemap": "2.3.6",
            "mageworx/module-info": ">=1.0.0",
            "mageworx/module-seoall": "2.8.5",
            "mageworx/module-seobase": "2.10.4",
            "mageworx/module-seobreadcrumbs": "2.1.3",
            "mageworx/module-seocategorygrid": "2.0.1",
            "mageworx/module-seocrosslinks": "2.4.9",
            "mageworx/module-seoextended": "2.5.8",
            "mageworx/module-seomarkup": "2.5.7",
            "mageworx/module-seoredirects": "2.5.0",
            "mageworx/module-seoreports": "1.0.1",
            "mageworx/module-seourls": "2.3.4",
            "mageworx/module-seoxtemplates": "2.12.1",
            "mageworx/module-xmlsitemap": "3.1.0"
        },
        "type": "metapackage"
    }
```

## Third

To remove the problem with the version constraints of the metapackage's dependencies:

### Remove Composer Package

```
composer remove mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate
```

### Reinstall Composer Package

```
compose require mageworx/module-seosuiteultimate
```